# Tool/solution for handle and catch error in app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, error-handling, bundle

I am looking after tool/solution that will catch and handle errors in my app. 
My application is in Ionic1. I expect from the solution to trace after the errors from the bundle.js and lead to the source code (through the sourceMap). Obviously I would like to send more data and parameters regarding the errors.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

I prefer free tools and lightweight solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) is a system that helps you organize your exceptions using a web application. You can setup an account on [getsentry.com](https://sentry.io/welcome/) or install it on your own server. You will need to create a new project and obtain the API key to interact with your application.

Comment: Thanks. I came across this tool. Do you use it? does it have access to sourceMap? so i can see the real error from my code?